# Performing a function on each matrix value

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am currently experimenting with Matlab functions. Basically I am trying to perform a function on each value found in a matrix such as the following simple example:

```
k = [1:100];
p = [45 60 98 100; 46 65 98 20; 47 65 96 50];
p(find(p)) = getSum(k, find(p), find(p) + 1);

function x = getSum(k, f, g, h)
x = sum(k(f:g));
end
```

Why the corresponding output matrix values are all 3, in other words why all indices are depending on the first calculated sum?

The output is the following:

```
p =

     3     3     3     3
     3     3     3     3
     3     3     3     3
```

Comment: You are assigning a scalar (output of your `getSum` function) to all elements in your `p` matrix.

Comment: What do you want to compute?  You have a 4x4 with indeces into k (1:100), it seems.  What do you want to sum?

Comment: This was just an example to illustrate the problem of passing arguments to a function for the main purposes of indexing an arbitrary array. My main objective is not to perform the sum, but to actually find a suitable way by which I can index an array depending on the function parameters and then apply the corresponding result (the one obtained after each indexing which in this case is the sum) to each matrix cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f:g` returns the value between `f(1,1)` and `g(1,1)`, so `1:2`.

`find(p)` returns the indices of non zero values. Since all values are non-zero, you get all indices.

So if we break down the statement `p(find(p)) = getSum(k, find(p), fin(p) + 1)`

We get

```
find(p) = 1:12
```

We then get 
`f = 1:12` and `g = 2:13` which lead to `k = 1:2` (as explained above)

finally `sum(1:2) = 3`

And this value is apply over `p(1:12)`, which is the same as `p(:,:)` (all the matrix)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. However, is there any other way how problems like this can be computed (i.e passing arguments to a function that depend on the current matrix position that will be used for indexing)? Please note that this was a simple case in order to illustrate the concept of passing arguments to a function which are used for indexing.

Comment: @Bran maybe, what you are looking for is `arrayfun`.

Comment: @CapeCode arrayfun() is one way how this can be done, but unfortunately it offers overheads during each function call. I am looking for an alternative way to speed up the process of modifying each cell by matrix manipulation/indexing...

Comment: @Bran Can't you share with us the actual opeartion that you intend to perform?